Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x\tan 2x- 2x\tan x}{(1-\cos 2x)^2}$
I want to find out given limit, which I solved as follows
$$\begin{align}
L &=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x\tan 2x- 2x\tan x}{(1-\cos 2x)^2} \tag1\\[6pt]
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan 2x- 2\tan x}{\dfrac{(1-\cos \ 2x)^2}{x}} \tag2 \\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan 2x- 2\tan x}{\left(\dfrac{1-\cos \ 2x}{2x}\right)^2\;4x} \tag3\\[6pt]
&=\frac14 \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1}{\left(\dfrac{1-\cos \ 2x}{2x}\right)^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan 2x -2\tan x}{x} \tag4
\end{align}$$
Now, we know that $\lim_{x\to 0} (1-\cos\ x)/x^2=1/2$, so
$$\begin{align}
L &=\frac14 \cdot 4 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\tan2x}{x} -\frac{2\tan x}{x}\right) \tag5\\[6pt]
&=\frac14 \cdot 4 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\left(2\frac{\tan 2x}{2x} -\frac{2\tan x}{x}\right) \tag6\\[6pt]
&=\frac14 \cdot 4\cdot (2-2) \tag7\\[6pt]
&=0 \tag8
\end{align}$$
But the given answer is $\frac12$, which I also checked from graph.
What is the mistake in above solution?

You know that $(1-\cos x)/x^2 \to \frac12$, but your expression for $L$ does not have this squared as, if you square it, there will be $x^4$ on the denominator. Instead,
\begin{align*}
L = \frac1{16} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{(2x)^2}\right)^2}\frac{\tan(2x)-2\tan x}{x^3}
=\frac1{16} \times 4\times 2 = \frac12
\end{align*}
using also that $(\tan(2x)-2\tan x)/x^3\to 2$

You were faster than me (+1)

You'll get me next time.

The standard approximation for $x\to 0$ we have:
$$
1 - \cos 2x \sim 2x^2
$$
Thus, the denominator $(1 - \cos 2x)^2$ behaves like:
$$
(1 - \cos 2x)^2 \sim (2x^2)^2 = 4x^4 \quad \text{as} \quad x \to 0.
$$
After if $x\to 0$, it is true (considering a Taylor's expansion),
$$
\tan 2x \approx 2x + \frac{(2x)^3}{3} = 2x + \frac{8x^3}{3}
$$
$$
\tan x \approx x + \frac{x^3}{3}
$$
Hence
$$
x(\tan 2x - 2 \tan x) \approx x\cdot \left[\left( 2x + \frac{8x^3}{3} \right) - 2 \left( x + \frac{x^3}{3} \right)\right]
 = 2x^4
$$
Definitively
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x\tan 2x- 2x\tan x}{(1-\cos 2x)^2}=\frac{2x^4}{4x^4}=\frac 12$$

Without Taylor: as $x\to0$, $x\sim t:=\tan x$, $\tan(2x)-2\tan x=2t\left(\frac1{1-t^2}-1\right)\sim2t^3$, and $1-\cos(2x)=\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}\sim2t^2$. But the OP's question ("What is the mistake in above solution?") was already answered. (thkxbtw)

@AnneBauval Thank you very very much.

@AnneBauval For the $2t(1/1-t^2 -1)$ you have used the Weierstrass substitution. Can you explain better why $=2t(1/1-t^2 -1)\sim 2t^3$? Thank you.

$\frac1{1-t^2}-1=\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}$.
